# How do Rakshasas look? Physical appearance of Rakshasas?

Tags: scripture, smriti, creation, rakshasa, ghosts

What are the various physical appearances of Rakshasas?

Comment: Well is there a difference between asuras and Rakshas?

Comment: This is a too broad question IMO. There are many types of rakshasas. Each dynasty had different physics appearance. Also, there's no need to add Hindu scripture as we are a Hinduism site and answers will be from scriptures ir based on scriptures even I they are from some author or saint's words.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Well I added Hindu scripture specifically so people don't reference Rakshasas in Indian TV shows and comics and stuff. And that's fine if there different types of rakshasas, the answerer can cite whatever description he comes across.

Comment: @AkshayKumarS Yes, there is a difference between Rakshasas and Asuras; they are different species, have different natures, and live on different planets.

Comment: Was Ravana, Asura or Rakshasa?

Comment: Arent Rakshas and Asura same ?

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto No. Asuras are children of Diti and Danava (hence Daityas and Danavas) and live in Rasatala. Whereas Rakshasas live elsewhere, are more tamasic, and eat humans.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma There, I omitted hindu scripture from question.

Comment: @ParabrahmanJyoti Ravan was a Brahmin from Father side and Rakshash from mother side. Rakshash species was created by Brahma to safeguard water, the abode of Vishnu.

Comment: Best description of Rakshash can be found in Valmiki Ramayan. Kabandh, Khar Dushan, Ravan, Kumbhakaran, and many more. They were not homogenous looking species. Valmiki ji describes the variety in great detail.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Citing from The Mahabharata, Book 7: Drona Parva: Ghatotkacha-badha Parva : SECTION CLXXV, describing the battle between Vikartana's son, Karna, and the Rakshasa Ghatotkacha.

> **Of blood-red eyes, Ghatotkacha was of gigantic form. His face was of
>   the hue of copper. His belly was low and sunken. The bristles on his
>   body all pointed upwards. His head was green. His ears were like
>   arrows. His cheek-bones were high. His mouth was large, extending from
>   ear to ear. His teeth were keen, and four of these were high and
>   pointed. His tongue and lips were very long and of a coppery hue. His
>   brows were long-extending. His nose was thick. His body was blue, and
>   neck red. Tall as a hill, he was terrible to behold. Of gigantic
>   frame, gigantic arms, and gigantic head, he was endued with great
>   might. Ugly and of hard limbs, the hair on his head was tied upwards
>   in a frightful shape. His hips were large and his navel was deep. Of
>   gigantic frame, the circumference of his body, however, was not great**.
>   The ornaments on his arms were proportionate. Possessed of great
>   powers of illusion, he was decked also in Angadas. He wore a cuirass
>   on his breast like a circle of fire on the breast of a mountain. On
>   his head was a bright and beautiful diadem made of gold, with every
>   part proportionate and beautiful, and looking like an arch. His
>   ear-rings were bright as the morning sun, and his garlands were made
>   of gold and exceedingly bright. He had on his body a gigantic armour
>   of brass of great effulgence.
>
> **A Rakshasa of terrible eyes, fiery mouth**, and blazing ear-rings, acted
>   as his driver, holding the reins, bright as the rays of the sun, of
>   his steeds in battle.
>
> Once more beholding that foremost of warriors, viz., Ghatotkacha,
>   fearlessly approaching him, surrounded by a **large number of Rakshasas
>   that resembled lions and tigers and infuriated elephants in prowess**,
>   some riding on elephants, some on cars, and some on horseback, all
>   armed with diverse weapons and clad in diverse kinds of mail and
>   diverse kinds of ornaments;
>
> **Ghatotkacha, that prince of Rakshasas**, who was endued with terrible
>   energy and strength, and who, inflamed with rage, **then looked like
>   Yama himself**. From his eyes, as he was excited with wrath, flames of
>   fire seemed to emit, like blazing drops of oil from a couple of
>   burning brands.
>
> Soon the **Rakshasa seemed to be like a porcupine with quills erect on
>   his body**.

History of the Devil: Brahmanism and Hinduism describes them as follows:

> Such are the general mischief-makers, the Asuras, the Pretas, or
>   ghosts, the Bhutas, or spook-spirits, the baby-killing Grahas, the
>   Rakshasas, **who are either giants or vampires**, not to mention all the
>   other demons of less power and importance.

Description of **Shuurpanakha** in [araNya kANDa](http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/aranya/sarga17/aranya_17_frame.htm) is as follows:

> She that **demoness** who is facially unpleasant one with that pleasant
>   faced one, pot bellied one with the slim-waisted one, wry-eyed one
>   with the broad-eyed one, coppery-haired one with the neatly tressed
>   one, ugly featured one with the charming featured one, brassy voiced
>   one with the gentle voiced one, deplorably oldish one with the
>   youngish one, crooked talker with the pleasant talker, ill-mannered
>   one with the well-mannered one, uncouth one with couth, abominable one
>   with amiable Rama spoke, besieged by Love-god.

One thing we can definitely conclude is that Rakshasas were ugly looking with huge body structure, long unkempt hair!